# Problem with Nav2 and RVIZ

Tags: navigation, ros2, ubuntu, nav2, stack

I'm trying to set up Nav2 (ROS2 Humble + Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS) to work in a simulation environment.

When I start the nav2 launch file, I see this on RVIZ, if from the Nav2 launch file I remove the comments on the remapping of the tf it will stop. With the remapping it will not work. All the tf are published on the /tf topic.

You can see [here](https://youtu.be/wppxAaGpb7g) what is happening to the robot.

Thanks.

This question is also publish [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ROS/comments/1au1r61/problem_with_nav2_and_rviz/).

Nav2 launch file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, PathJoinSubstitution
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription, DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from nav2_common.launch import ReplaceString, RewrittenYaml


def generate_launch_description():
    # Specify the name of the package
    pkg_name = "scout_navigation"
    namespace = "scout_mini"

    config_file_dir = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(pkg_name), "config")

    # Arguments and parameters
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration("use_sim_time", default="true")
    map_name = LaunchConfiguration("map_name", default="workshop_big_cartographer.yaml")

    declare_use_sim_time_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        "use_sim_time",
        default_value=use_sim_time,
        description="Use simulation (Gazebo) clock if true",
    )

    declare_map_name_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        "map_name", default_value=map_name, description="Specify map name"
    )

    # Add namespace to robot_localization parameter files
    namespaced_ekf_localization_params = ReplaceString(
        source_file=os.path.join(config_file_dir, "ekf_localization_with_gps.yaml"),
        replacements={"namespace": namespace},
    )

    namespaced_nav2_params = ReplaceString(
        source_file=os.path.join(config_file_dir, "nav2_params.yaml"),
        replacements={"/namespace": ("/", namespace)},
    )

    namespaced_nav2_params = RewrittenYaml(
        source_file=namespaced_nav2_params,
        root_key=namespace,
        param_rewrites={
            "yaml_filename": PathJoinSubstitution(
                [get_package_share_directory(pkg_name), "maps", map_name]
            )
        },
        convert_types=True,
    )

    # Nodes
    rviz2_node = Node(
        namespace=namespace,
        package="rviz2",
        executable="rviz2",
        name="rviz2",
        arguments=[
            "-d",
            os.path.join(
                get_package_share_directory(pkg_name),
                "rviz",
                "scout_mini_navigation.rviz",
            ),
        ],
        parameters=[{"use_sim_time": use_sim_time}],
        output="screen",
        # remappings=[("/tf", "tf"), ("/tf_static", "tf_static")],
    )

    robot_localization_local_node = Node(
        namespace=namespace,
        package="robot_localization",
        executable="ekf_node",
        name="ekf_local_filter_node",
        output="screen",
        parameters=[namespaced_ekf_localization_params, {"use_sim_time": use_sim_time}],
        remappings=[
            #    ("/tf", "tf"),
            #    ("/tf_static", "tf_static"),
            ("odometry/filtered", "odometry/filtered/local"),
        ],
    )

    robot_localization_global_node = Node(
        namespace=namespace,
        package="robot_localization",
        executable="ekf_node",
        name="ekf_global_filter_node",
        output="screen",
        parameters=[namespaced_ekf_localization_params, {"use_sim_time": use_sim_time}],
        remappings=[
            #    ("/tf", "tf"),
            #    ("/tf_static", "tf_static"),
            ("odometry/filtered", "odometry/filtered/global"),
        ],
    )

    navsat_transform_node = Node(
        namespace=namespace,
        package="robot_localization",
        executable="navsat_transform_node",
        name="navsat_transform_node",
        output="screen",
        parameters=[namespaced_ekf_localization_params, {"use_sim_time": use_sim_time}],
        remappings=[
            ("imu/data", "imu"),
            ("gps/fix", "gps"),
            #    ("/tf", "tf"),
            #    ("/tf_static", "tf_static"),
            ("odometry/filtered", "odometry/filtered/global"),
        ],
    )

    nav2_bt_node = Node(
        namespace=namespace,
        package="nav2_bt_navigator",
        executable="bt_navigator",
        name="bt_navigator",
        output="screen",
        respawn=False,
        respawn_delay=2.0,
        parameters=[namespaced_nav2_params, {"use_sim_time": use_sim_time}],
        arguments=["--ros-args", "--log-level", "info"],
        # remappings=[("/tf", "tf"), ("/tf_static", "tf_static")],
    )

    nav2_planner_node = Node(
        namespace=namespace,
        package="nav2_planner",
        executable="planner_server",
        name="planner_server",
        output="screen",
        respawn=False,
        respawn_delay=2.0,
        parameters=[namespaced_nav2_params, {"use_sim_time": use_sim_time}],
        arguments=["--ros-args", "--log-level", "info"],
        # remappings=[("/tf", "tf"), ("/tf_static", "tf_static")],
    )

    nav2_controller_node = Node(
        namespace=namespace,
        package="nav2_controller",
        executable="controller_server",
        name="controller_server",
        output="screen",
        respawn=False,
        respawn_delay=2.0,
        parameters=[namespaced_nav2_params, {"use_sim_time": use_sim_time}],
        arguments=["--ros-args", "--log-level", "info"],
        remappings=[
            # ("/tf", "tf"),
            # ("/tf_static", "tf_static"),
            ("/cmd_vel", "cmd_vel_nav"),
        ],
    )

    nav2_map_server_node = Node(
        namespace=namespace,
        package="nav2_map_server",
        executable="map_server",
        name="map_server",
        output="screen",
        respawn=False,
        respawn_delay=2.0,
        parameters=[namespaced_nav2_params, {"use_sim_time": use_sim_time}],
        arguments=["--ros-args", "--log-level", "info"],
        # remappings=[("/tf", "tf")],
    )

    nav2_amcl_node = Node(
        namespace=namespace,
        package="nav2_amcl",
        executable="amcl",
        name="amcl",
        output="screen",
        respawn=False,
        respawn_delay=2.0,
        parameters=[namespaced_nav2_params, {"use_sim_time": use_sim_time}],
        arguments=["--ros-args", "--log-level", "info"],
        # remappings=[("/tf", "tf"), ("/tf_static", "tf_static")],
    )

    nav2_behavior_server_node = Node(
        namespace=namespace,
        package="nav2_behaviors",
        executable="behavior_server",
        name="behavior_server",
        output="screen",
        respawn=False,
        respawn_delay=2.0,
        parameters=[namespaced_nav2_params, {"use_sim_time": use_sim_time}],
        arguments=["--ros-args", "--log-level", "info"],
        # remappings=[("/tf", "tf"), ("/tf_static", "tf_static")],
    )

    nav2_smoother_server_node = Node(
        namespace=namespace,
        package="nav2_smoother",
        executable="smoother_server",
        name="smoother_server",
        output="screen",
        respawn=False,
        respawn_delay=2.0,
        parameters=[namespaced_nav2_params, {"use_sim_time": use_sim_time}],
        arguments=["--ros-args", "--log-level", "info"],
        # remappings=[("/tf", "tf"), ("/tf_static", "tf_static")],
    )

    nav2_waypoint_follower_node = Node(
        namespace=namespace,
        package="nav2_waypoint_follower",
        executable="waypoint_follower",
        name="waypoint_follower",
        output="screen",
        respawn=False,
        respawn_delay=2.0,
        parameters=[namespaced_nav2_params, {"use_sim_time": use_sim_time}],
        arguments=["--ros-args", "--log-level", "info"],
        # remappings=[("/tf", "tf"), ("/tf_static", "tf_static")],
    )

    nav2_lifecycle_manager_node = Node(
        namespace=namespace,
        package="nav2_lifecycle_manager",
        executable="lifecycle_manager",
        name="lifecycle_manager_navigation",
        output="screen",
        arguments=["--ros-args", "--log-level", "info"],
        parameters=[
            {"use_sim_time": use_sim_time},
            {"autostart": True},
            {"bond_timeout": 4.0},
            {"attempt_respawn_reconnection": True},
            {"bond_respawn_max_duration": 10.0},
            {
                "node_names": [
                    "map_server",
                    "controller_server",
                    "planner_server",
                    "amcl",
                    "behavior_server",
                    "smoother_server",
                    "waypoint_follower",
                    "bt_navigator",
                ]
            },
        ],
    )

    ld = LaunchDescription()

    # Declare the launch options
    ld.add_action(declare_use_sim_time_arg)
    ld.add_action(declare_map_name_arg)

    # Add the commands to the launch description
    ld.add_action(robot_localization_local_node)
    ld.add_action(robot_localization_global_node)
    # ld.add_action(navsat_transform_node) # TODO: questa linea e' commentata per evitare di attivare tutte le volte il servizio GPS.
    ld.add_action(nav2_map_server_node)
    ld.add_action(nav2_controller_node)
    ld.add_action(nav2_planner_node)
    ld.add_action(nav2_behavior_server_node)
    ld.add_action(nav2_amcl_node)
    ld.add_action(nav2_smoother_server_node)
    ld.add_action(nav2_waypoint_follower_node)
    ld.add_action(nav2_bt_node)
    ld.add_action(nav2_lifecycle_manager_node)

    ld.add_action(rviz2_node)

    return ld
```

Nav2 params file

```
### NAV2 config file ###
local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      rolling_window: True
      width: 3
      height: 3
      resolution: 0.05
      footprint: "[ [0.290, 0.3075], [0.290, -0.3075], [-0.290, 0.3075], [-0.290, -0.3075] ]" # set on the size of the Scout Mini 615x580mm
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /namespace/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /namespace/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.1
      always_send_full_costmap: True
    
  local_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True
  
  local_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      footprint: "[ [0.290, 0.3075], [0.290, -0.3075], [-0.290, 0.3075], [-0.290, -0.3075] ]" # set on the size of the Scout Mini 615x580mm
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: True
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /namespace/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /namespace/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.1
      always_send_full_costmap: True

  global_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True

  global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner"
      use_astar: false
      allow_unknown: true
      tolerance: 0.5

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    controller_frequency: 20.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    failure_tolerance: 0.3
    odom_topic: /namespace/odom
    progress_checker_plugins: ["progress_checker"] # progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker" For Humble and older
    goal_checker_plugin: ["goal_checker"]
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    goal_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      stateful: True
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: True
      min_vel_x: 0.0
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 2.77
      max_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_theta: 1.0
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      max_speed_xy: 2.77 # this is set for Scout Mini (max speed 10km/h)
      min_speed_theta: 0.0
      # Add high threshold velocity for turtlebot 3 issue.
      # https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/issues/75
      # TODO: I don't know what to set for this 6 parameters, which is the maximum accelaratin for the robot?
      acc_lim_x: 2.5
      acc_lim_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_theta: 3.2
      decel_lim_x: -2.5
      decel_lim_y: 0.0
      decel_lim_theta: -3.2
      vx_samples: 20
      vy_samples: 5
      vtheta_samples: 20
      sim_time: 1.7
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      angular_granularity: 0.025
      transform_tolerance: 0.2
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      stateful: True
      critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist"]
      BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /namespace/odom
    bt_loop_duration: 10
    default_server_timeout: 20
    # 'default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml' and 'default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml' are use defaults:
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_to_pose_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # They can be set here or via a RewrittenYaml remap from a parent launch file to Nav2.
    plugin_lib_names:
      - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_smooth_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
      - nav2_assisted_teleop_action_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_bt_node
      - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
      - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_globally_updated_goal_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_is_path_valid_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
      - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_local_action_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
      - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
      - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
      - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
      - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_path_expiring_timer_condition
      - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
      - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_path_longer_on_approach_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_assisted_teleop_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_charging_condition_bt_node

bt_navigator_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    alpha1: 0.2
    alpha2: 0.2
    alpha3: 0.2
    alpha4: 0.2
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "base_link"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 25.0 # 25 meters for indoor is the max for RPlidar A3, put -1 as default value and it will take the max value available
    laser_min_range: 0.2 # 0.2 meters is the min for RPlidar A3, -1 as default value and it will take the min value available
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 60
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::DifferentialMotionModel"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_min_a: 0.2
    update_min_d: 0.25
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05 # not used in likelihood mode
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05 # not used in likelihood mode
    scan_topic: /namespace/scan
    map_topic: /namespace/map
    set_initial_pose: true # this should be set to false in real world scenario. 
    always_reset_initial_pose: false
    first_map_only: false
    initial_pose:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      yaw: 3.14

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    yaml_filename: "workshop.yaml"
    topic_name: /namespace/map
    frame_id: map

behavior_server:
  ros__parameters:
    local_costmap_topic: /namespace/local_costmap/costmap_raw
    local_footprint_topic: /namespace/local_costmap/published_footprint
    global_costmap_topic: /namespace/global_costmap/costmap_raw
    global_footprint_topic: /namespace/global_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    behavior_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "drive_on_heading", "wait", "assisted_teleop"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/BackUp"
    drive_on_heading:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/DriveOnHeading"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Wait"
    assisted_teleop:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/AssistedTeleop"
    local_frame: odom
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_timeout: 0.1
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    loop_rate: 100
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"   
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 2000 

smoother_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: /namespace/global_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: /namespace/global_costmap/published_footprint
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_timeout: 0.1
    smoother_plugins: ["simple_smoother"]
    simple_smoother:
      plugin: "nav2_smoother::SimpleSmoother"
      tolerance: 1.0e-10
      do_refinement: True
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have conflicting TF publishers that are publishing the same transform to different spots resulting in the jitter.

If you visualize in different frames of reference (base_link, odom, map, etc) you should be able to identify what transform is being republished differently (because in some frame it'll stop happening; at which that and below is fine).

Comment: Selecting the base_link frame the robot is stopped and the map is moving up and down.